# Website not showing in search results when searching with spaces

Tags: seo, html, css, search, browsers

Website not showing in search results when searching with spaces

Example: mywebsite.com

(Without spaces) When i search "mywebsite" it shows #1

(With spaces) When i search "my website" it doesnt even show in the results list

I have put multiple sites live but this is the first time ive ran into this issue.

I have also added multiple instances of the name on the site with spaces to try to help the search but it didnt help.

Is there something im missing? or is this just the more content added and traffic that comes to the site it will fix on its own.